# Notepad++ insert new line at every nth occurrence of a string/character

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ *Find and Replace* feature, I would like to insert a new line at every *n*th occurrence of a character or string (a comma in my case).

I have tried the regex below using "Regular expression" mode, but no luck.

**Find what:** `((,){1000})`

**Replace with**: `\1\n`

Comment: Would this work: `(((.*?), ){1000})`? I couldn't understand the regex.

Comment: The regex in your comment looks closer, have you tried it?

Comment: It is not quite clear: every nth occurrence in the *file* or *line*?

Comment: If a line is meant, you may use `(?:[^\n\r,]*,){2}` (or your approach will also work - `(?:.*?,){2}`) -> `$&\n` to insert a `\n` after every second `,`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mean to add a newline after nth occurrence of any string on a line, I'd use

```
(?:.*?,){2}
```

and replace with `$&\n` (or `$&\r\n`) where `.*?` matches any 0+ chars other than line break characters, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of `,`. The `$&` is the backreference to the whole match value (`2` is used for the demo to look cleaner, `1000` is a rather big value). See a demo showing that a newline is placed after each second `,`.

With a single char, you'd better use a negated character class (but add line break chars there to force the pattern to not overflow across lines):

```
(?:[^\n\r,]*,){2}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do this in vim?

Comment: @DanielvanFlymen: In Vim, you need to replace with `\r` to insert a newline. And since Vim character classes do not match line breaks, there is no need to use `\n\r` in the `[...]`. And the backreference to the whole match is `&`. So, try `:%s/\([^,]*,\)\{2}/&\r/g`.