# In Notepad++ , how to replace with new line, every last occurrence of a pattern in a line?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ , how to replace with new line, every last occurrence of a pattern in a line?

For Example:

Before:

```
abc/acd/cd 
ac/sd
ace/edf/cd/cfd
```

After:

```
abc/acd
cd
ac
sd
ace/edf/cd
cfd
```

Similar To: 
[Notepad++ insert new line at every nth occurrence of a string/character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299223/notepad-insert-new-line-at-every-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-character/50289856#50289856)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\K/`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^   : beginning of line
.+  : 1 or more any character but newline
\K  : forget all we have seen until this position
/   : a slash
```